# Boundedness of funcions in $L^2(0,T;H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $u_{k} \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^2(0,T;H)$ (the $\rightharpoonup$ means "weakly convergent to"). Assume  one has the uniform bounds $$\mathrm{essential~sup}_{0\leq t\leq T}\|u_{k}(t)\|\leq C,\forall k$$ for some constant $C$. Show that $$\mathrm{essential~sup}_{0\leq t\leq T}\|u(t)\|\leq C.$$

Remark: I know the inner product of $u_k$ and $v$ satisfies $\int_{a}^{b}(v, u_{k})\mathrm{d}t\leq C\|v\||b-a| ~\mathrm{for} ~0\leq a\leq b\leq T~~\mathrm{and~ each}~~v\in H$, but how to apply this observation to deduce the boundedness of $u$?

Note that the assumption  $u_k \rightharpoonup  u$ weakly in $L^2(0,T;H)$
means 
$$\begin{equation}
\int_0^T (v,u(t)) dt=\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^T(v,u_k(t)),  \,\,\forall v\in L^2(0,T;H)
\end{equation}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this :
$$ \text{essential}\sup_{0\leq t \leq T} \|u_k(t)\| \leq C$$

$$\Rightarrow \qquad \langle u_k(t),u_k(t)\rangle \leq C^2 a.e$$

$$\Rightarrow \qquad \langle u_k(t),u(t)\rangle + \langle u_k(t),u_k(t)-u(t)\rangle \leq C^2 a.e$$

$$\Rightarrow \qquad \langle u_k(t),u(t)\rangle + \langle u_k(t)-u(t),u_k(t)-u(t)\rangle + \langle u(t),u_k(t)-u(t)\rangle\leq C^2 a.e$$

$$\Rightarrow \qquad \langle u_k(t),u(t)\rangle + \|u_k(t)-u(t)\|^2 + \langle u(t),u_k(t)-u(t)\rangle\leq C^2 a.e$$

$$\Rightarrow \qquad \langle u_k(t),u(t)\rangle + \langle u(t),u_k(t)-u(t)\rangle\leq C^2 a.e$$

And, as this is valid for all k, you can take the limit, and because $\langle u_k(t),u(t)\rangle \to \langle u(t),u(t)\rangle$ and $\langle u(t),u_k(t)-u(t)\rangle \to 0$, you get

$$\qquad \langle u(t),u(t)\rangle + 0\leq C^2 a.e$$

Comment: It seems you did not employ the definition of weak convergence correctly, namely $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ should be read as a functional in the dual of $L^2(0,T;H)$ act on $u_{k}$ (or $u$), instead of something like $u_k$ acts on $u_k$ itself.

Comment: But $L^2(0,T;H)$ is a hilbert space isn't it? so it's own dual. Then we can see u both as an element of $L^2(0,T;H)$ and an element of the dual of $L^2(0,T;H)$. Or A I mistaken? But indeed, there seems to be a mistake, as $u_k \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^2(0,T;H)$ and not $u_k(t) \rightharpoonup u(t)$ in $H$ for all $t$

Comment: Indeed, we need to be smarter than that : if $u_k$ converge in $L^2$ to $u$, there exist a subsequence that converge pointwise to $u$. Then you take the limit for this subsequence

Comment: How would one show there is a pointwise convergent subsequence? Would like to give some details?

Comment: It is a classical result. You can find a demonstration here : http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6337/fall07/section2.4b.pdf

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work here